# Can't Add Any Card To Apple Wallet (iPhone 6s Plus)

Tags: iphone, apple-pay

I am unable to add ***any card*** to Apple Wallet for use with Apple Pay. When I select "Add Credit or Debit Card", a progress indicator spins for a second or two, and then the following error appears, ***without ever presenting the camera***:

> "Could Not Add Card — Try again later or contact your card issuer for
>   more information"

——[image: **enter image description here**]

Of course, contacting the card issuer would be pointless, because the camera never had a chance to read the card I'm trying to add.

I followed all of the instructions at this Apple support article to no avail:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205630

I also tried turning Passcode Off, restarting the phone, and then reestablishing a new passcode when prompted by the Wallet app.

After that didn't work, I did a complete reset of all data and content on the iPhone, with still no luck. I can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: Do you have a card enabled on an Apple Watch?

Comment: @Trellis — No, I don't have an Apple Watch. I have cards enabled on another iPhone which work perfectly. It can't be a matter of a particular card causing the problem, because the camera never gets to the step of reading the card I'm trying to add.

Comment: I've had a similar problem adding a Discover card. The instructions I received from Discover through email support included steps that did not seem possible when adding a card to Apple Pay. I simply haven't taken the time to attempt to solve the problem because I still have Apple Pay configured successfully on my Apple Watch, and the only reason I was trying to activate it on the iPhone again was to try to solve an issue with one merchant that appeared not to be able to function with the watch.

Comment: Hope Apple can help you. Otherwise, you'll likely be looking at the necessity to involve both Apple and the card carrier, which would seem to me to be a nearly insurmountable obstacle.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue- did you ever get this resolved? Thx!